# UITableView with Json file, loading images to cell disappear

Tags: ios, json, image, uitableview

I am using asyncimageview classes nicely provided by: http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

I am getting image urls from a json file and loading each image to a cell.

Problem:

When i scroll up, and scroll back down to the same cell, the image reloads (disappears and appears again). I can't figure out why the image keeps reloading? Does anyone have suggestions or a solution to how I could make it stop? Thanks in advance!

```
   // Asks the data source to return a cell to insert in a particular table view location

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    //Gets the current news article
    NewsArticle *theCurrentArticle = [self.listofNewsArticles objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    //Gets the title from the current article
    NSString *theTitle = theCurrentArticle.title;

    //Gets the image url 
    NSString *imageUrl = theCurrentArticle.imageURL;

    //Gets the description of the current news article
    NSString *theDescription = theCurrentArticle.description;


    NewsCustomCell *cell = (NewsCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsContent"];

    __block NewsCustomCell *aCell;

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    if (cell == nil) {
        aCell = (NewsCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsContent"];
    } else {
        AsyncImageView* oldImage = (AsyncImageView*)
        [cell.contentView viewWithTag:999];
        [oldImage removeFromSuperview];
    }



    AsyncImageView *imageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 100)];
    imageView.tag = 999;

          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [imageView loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

              cell.titleLabel.text = theTitle;
              cell.descriptionLabel.text = theDescription;
              cell.imageLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

});

         });



    return cell;



}
```

Heres what the current app looks like:

[image]

Solution:

Just worked with this class I finally found. 
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage
This handles caching, async downloads. Wish I found this sooner..

Comment: Sounds like all your images have tag 999. What if you made that tag something unique? Like a serialized version of the index path per row?

Comment: Hmm, i need to tag there so if it detects an image already in the view it removes it from the superview. This is so you don't have images overlapping each other.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have Write AsyncImageView and ImageCache and ImageCacheObject classes.
Write this code inside cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    Quest_Forum *Quest_ForumObj=[queArr objectAtIndex:i+indexPath.row];
  //  NSLog(@"cell for row at... i val.. %d",i+indexPath.row);

    for(UIView * view in cell.contentView.subviews){
        if([view isKindOfClass:[AsyncImageView class]])
        {
           // NSLog(@"remove old images");
            [view removeFromSuperview];
            view = nil;
        }
    }

    AsyncImageView *asyncImageView = nil;

    UIImageView *cellImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1]; // Inside tableview i have taken tableviewcell and given tag 1 to that imageview

    asyncImageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cellImage.frame] ;
    [asyncImageView loadImageFromURL:Quest_ForumObj.Quest_Image];
    asyncImageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; 
    [cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImageView];


    UILabel *lblQuest = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2]; // Given tag 2 to the label inside tableViewCell
    lblQuest.text=Quest_ForumObj.Question;
```

In ImageCacheObject.h

```
@class ImageCacheObject;

@interface ImageCache : NSObject 
{
    NSUInteger totalSize;  // total number of bytes
    NSUInteger maxSize;    // maximum capacity
    NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger totalSize;

-(id)initWithMaxSize:(NSUInteger) max;
-(void)insertImage:(UIImage*)image withSize:(NSUInteger)sz forKey:(NSString*)key;
-(UIImage*)imageForKey:(NSString*)key;
```

In ImageCacheObject.m

```
#import "ImageCacheObject.h"

@synthesize totalSize;

-(id)initWithMaxSize:(NSUInteger) max  
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        totalSize = 0;
        maxSize = max;
        myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc // Don't write this method if you are using ARC 
{
    [myDictionary release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)insertImage:(UIImage*)image withSize:(NSUInteger)sz forKey:(NSString*)key
{
   // NSLog(@"count of insert image%d",sz);
    ImageCacheObject *object = [[ImageCacheObject alloc] initWithSize:sz Image:image];
    while (totalSize + sz > maxSize) 
    {
        NSDate *oldestTime;
        NSString *oldestKey;
        for (NSString *key in [myDictionary allKeys]) 
        {
            ImageCacheObject *obj = [myDictionary objectForKey:key];
            if (oldestTime == nil || [obj.timeStamp compare:oldestTime] == NSOrderedAscending) 
            {
                oldestTime = obj.timeStamp;
                oldestKey = key;
            }
        }
        if (oldestKey == nil) 
            break; // shoudn't happen
        ImageCacheObject *obj = [myDictionary objectForKey:oldestKey];
        totalSize -= obj.size;
        [myDictionary removeObjectForKey:oldestKey];
    }
    [myDictionary setObject:object forKey:key];
    [object release];
}

-(UIImage*)imageForKey:(NSString*)key 
{
    ImageCacheObject *object = [myDictionary objectForKey:key];
    if (object == nil)
        return nil;
    [object resetTimeStamp];
    return object.image;
}
```

In ImageCacheObject.h

```
@interface ImageCacheObject : NSObject 
{
    NSUInteger size;    // size in bytes of image data
    NSDate *timeStamp;  // time of last access
    UIImage *image;     // cached image
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger size;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSDate *timeStamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) UIImage *image;

-(id)initWithSize:(NSUInteger)sz Image:(UIImage*)anImage;
-(void)resetTimeStamp;
```

In ImageCacheObject.m

```
@synthesize size;
@synthesize timeStamp;
@synthesize image;

-(id)initWithSize:(NSUInteger)sz Image:(UIImage*)anImage
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        size = sz;
        timeStamp = [[NSDate date] retain];
        image = [anImage retain];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)resetTimeStamp 
{
    [timeStamp release];
    timeStamp = [[NSDate date] retain];
}

-(void) dealloc 
{
    [timeStamp release];
    [image release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: No I don't have image cache or image cache object. :/ Could you please point me to some sources? I'll look around as well. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Shah, thanks for trying to help out! I really tried working with imageCache this morning, but then found https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage which handles all of this really well. Thanks for your reply though i appreciate it !